# MSTest Results "In Progress"

Tags: mstest

Once in a while we are getting strange results from MSTEST. All Unit Tests seem to started at the same time - MSTest is just triggering them and moving on. After all of them are started the test run is aborted.

What seems strange is the Result "In Progress" - I can not find anything about such result in MSTest documentation.

MSTest is started and executed from within Jenkins and most of the time everything works fine as it should.

Any help or ideas about the situation would be appretiated.

Here is the exact output with test names deleted:

```
20:57:22 Results               Top Level Tests
20:57:22 -------               ---------------
20:57:22 In Progress           (Test1)
20:57:22 In Progress           (Test2)
20:57:23 In Progress           (Test3)
20:57:23 In Progress           (Test4)
20:57:23 0/4 test(s) Passed, 4 Aborted
20:57:23 
20:57:23 Summary
20:57:23 -------
20:57:23 Test Run Aborted.
20:57:23   Aborted  4
20:57:23   ----------
20:57:23   Total    4
```

Comment: If you open the `trx` file (if you create one) from visual studio you should see the reason why the tests were aborted.

Comment: It only contains a warning, that some assembly is indirectly referenced - but this warning also there when tests run fine and everything is OK.

Comment: We have the same issue on one of our build servers (running Jenkins and MSTest), did you ever find out the cause of the problem? I get no clue from the trx file either.

Comment: Got it working, enabled LargeAddressAware on QTAgent32 (see answer below)

Answer (score 1):

Try make QTAgent32 large address aware.

Had the same issue with a build server running Jenkins and MSTest, a bunch of tests reported status "In Progress" and was later aborted.

This helped:

1. Start a Visual Studio Command Prompt (Run as administrator might be needed)
2. Execute the following:

> C:>editbin "Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   11.0\Common7\IDE\QTAgent32.exe" /LargeAddressAware

For more info see [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/calvin_hsia/archive/2012/06/27/10324809.aspx).